# How do I press "<C-L> <C-W>l<C-W>_" in Vim?

Tags: vim

In one of the vim config files I have noticed this keyboard mapping
`map <C-L> <C-W>l<C-W>_` supposedly for easier moving in tabs and windows. What does that translate to keyboard presses? What is that underscore at the end for?

Comment: Isn't that the "target" of the map?

Comment: Yes my question is how do I actually press that? I've tried CTRL+L CTRL+W l followed by CTRL+W any many other combinations but to no avail.

Comment: *whoosh* I guess it missed ;-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The command `map <C-L> <C-W>l<C-W>_`  maps <kbd>Ctrl-L</kbd> to <kbd>Ctrl-W</kbd>, <kbd>`l`</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl-W</kbd>,  <kbd>_</kbd>.

You invoke this binding by just pressing <kbd>Ctrl-L</kbd>. To invoke what it binds to you would type <kbd>Ctrl-W</kbd>, then <kbd>`l`</kbd>, followed by <kbd>Ctrl-W</kbd> again, and finally <kbd>_</kbd> (which on a US keyboard is shift-hyphen). This is two separate bindings, `<C-W>l` moves the cursor to the window to the right, and `<C-W>_` resizes current window to the maximum possible vertical size.

Answer (score 3):

The <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd><kbd>l</kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd><kbd>_</kbd> keys sequence is somewhat too long so someone has created a shortcut ("`map`ping" in Vim-speak): <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> for it.

`<C-w>l<C-w>_` moves the the cursor to the window on the right (`<C-w>l`) and maximizes it vertically (`<C-w>_`).

Mappings always follow the same structure:

1. `map` (or `imap` for *insert* mode mapping, `nmap` for *normal* mode mapping, etc.)
2. some whitespace
3. the shortcut you want, here `<C-L>`
4. some whitespace
5. the sequence of commands triggered by the shortcut

See `:help windows` for more info on window management and `:help mapping` for more info on mappings.